# Adsense gives me an error if I click several times on the same link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adsense

I am using adsense (With Ruby on Rails 6) on localhost, I have about 3 ads per page. If I enter a page once and from it I navigate to other pages I don't get any error but if I open the same link several times I get this error.

```
{"message": "adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them.",
"name": "TagError",
"pbr": true}
```

The call I make to the method mentioned in the error is the following, which is only in the index.html file (base html):

```
<script>
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.adsbygoogle'), function(){
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    });
  </script>
```

I tried to put separately this code under each ad

```
 <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

and it doesn't work.

I also tried to put a random "key" attribute to each  element and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - that error, while annoying, is harmless. It means that you did unnecessary `window.adsbygoogle.push({});` call and that call was ignored. It's hard to say where those extra `.push()` calls come from as looking at your code you should be doing the same number of `.push()` as elements you have on a page. Can you add logging to see how many times your function is called and how many actual `.adsbygoogle` elements you have on a page?

When you say that `<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>`  doesn't work. What do you mean exactly? Ads are not initialized or that you still getting JS error?

Comment: When I say that it does not work, it is because the console displays the error that I have mentioned but everything seems to work correctly. It must be what you said, that it runs more times than it should but it is strange. My (provisional) solution is to catch that exception and do nothing with it.

try {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.adsbygoogle'), function(){
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    });
}
catch (e) {
   // Do nothing
}

Comment: If you give a link to your website - I can take a look. Generally if you match correctly number of `<ins class="adsbgyoogle">` elements with `adsbygoogle.push({});` calls - you shouldn't see any errors.